# Grab the first and last element for every sequence

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with 3 types of sequences and their positions that are reoccurring as such:

```
seq1 2
seq1 5
seq1 10
seq3 15
seq3 34
seq3 60
seq2 100
seq2 110
seq2 200
seq3 210
seq3 250
seq3 300
seq1 310
seq1 330
seq1 400
```

The second value is always unique denoting a position and is sorted, hence why the sequences are scattered.

For every time a sequence starts, I want to grab the minimum and max of that sequence. Output should be (seq min max)

```
seq1 2 10
seq3 15 60
seq2 100 200
seq3 210 300
seq1 310 400
```

Is it possible to do this in bash with awk or anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'p != $1 {if (NR>1) print p, first, last; first=$2} {p=$1; last=$2} 
END{print p, first, last}' file
```

```
seq1 2 10
seq3 15 60
seq2 100 200
seq3 210 300
seq1 310 400
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk

```
$ awk ' { if(NR>1 && p!=$1) { print p,min,max; max=min=""} min=min?min:$2; max=$2; p=$1 } 
END { print p,min,max } ' adrian.txt
seq1 2 10
seq3 15 60
seq2 100 200
seq3 210 300
seq1 310 400

$
```